# In laravel in controller pass variable to one function to another function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, controller

I am coding in Laravel, How can I pass variable to one function to another function in Controller,

In controller file I have 2 functions like this

```
public function hiringEmployee(Request $request)
{
    $hireEmployee = new EmployeeHire();
    $hireEmployee->candidateName = $request->get('candidateName');

    $file = $request->file('file');
    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('uploads/cv', $name);

    $hireEmployee->file = $name;
    $hireEmployee->save();

    return redirect('list-candidate');
}


public function assignInterview(Request $request, $id)
{
    $assignInterview = EmployeeHire::find($id);
    $interview = $request->get('interview');
    $assignto = $request->get('assignto');
    $dateTime = $request->get('dateTime');
    $note = $request->get('note');

    $interviewDetails = ([
        'interview' => $interview,
        'assign_to' => $assignto,
        'date_time' => $dateTime,
        'note'      => $note,
    ]);

    $assignInterview->interview_details = $interviewDetails;
    $assignInterview->save();


    Mail::send('emails.hireemployee', ['candidateName' => $candidateName], function ($message) use ($assignto, $name) {
        $message->subject('Interview For New Candidate!');
        $message->from('hrm@wcg.com', 'HRM');
        $message->to($mail);
        $message->attach('uploads/cv/'.$name);
    });

    return redirect('list-candidate');
}
```

I want to use `$candidateName` and `$name` in `assignInterview()` function from `hiringEmployee()` function.

How can I do it?

Comment: If one of the below posts answered your question **please may you mark it as accepted** :) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to use the `$name` and `$candidateName` directly from the other function as they look like they are for two different requests, however, it looks like you're saving that data to database when you're creating a new `EmployeeHire` in your `hiringEmployee()` method so you should already have access to that information in your `assignInterview()` method:

```
$assignInterview = EmployeeHire::find($id); // this is where you loading the model

$candidateName = $assignInterview->candidateName;
$name  = $assignInterview->file;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your situation , you can use two approach:

**#1**

Use Session Variable as below:

```
Session::put('candidateName', $candidateName);
```

Then:

```
$value = Session::get('candidateName');
```

**#2**

Use class attribute:

```
class acontroller extends Controller
{    
    private $classCandidateName;

}
```

Comment: And I wrote my whole assignInterview() function in acontroller class???

Comment: In your Controller that you have two functions, add two attribute into your class, after that you can call and use the value in attribute. if you want to call function another time, you can retrieve data from your database and use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
public function hiringEmployee(Request $request)
{
    $hireEmployee = new EmployeeHire();
    $hireEmployee->candidateName = $request->get('candidateName');

    $file = $request->file('file');
    $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move('uploads/cv', $name);

    $hireEmployee->file = $name;
    $hireEmployee->save();

    return redirect('list-candidate');
}


public function assignInterview(Request $request, $id)
{
    $assignInterview = EmployeeHire::find($id);
     if(is_null($assignInterview)){
         return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['Error message here']);
     }

    $interviewDetails = ([
        'interview' => $request->get('interview'),
        'assign_to' => $request->get('assignto'),
        'date_time' => $request->get('dateTime'),
        'note'      => $request->get('note'),
    ]);

    $assignInterview->interview_details = $interviewDetails;
    $assignInterview->save();


    Mail::send('emails.hireemployee', ['candidateName' => $assignInterview->candidateName], function ($message) use ($assignto, $assignInterview->file) {
        $message->subject('Interview For New Candidate!');
        $message->from('hrm@wcg.com', 'HRM');
        $message->to($mail);
        $message->attach('uploads/cv/'.$assignInterview->file);
    });

    return redirect('list-candidate');
}
```

Please, you should to be careful with find($id). If it is a null, you will get an error.

Have fun!